# How to load field with ajax in index view on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this structure on the views of my class

**views/cards/index**

```
<% render @cards %>
```

**views/cards/_card**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <p><%= card.name %></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="link-show-phone">Show Phone</a></p>
  <p><div id="show-phone-<%= card.id %>"></div></p>
  <p><a href="#" class="link-show-email">Show Email</a><p>
  <p><div id="show-email-<%= card.id %>"></div><p>
</div>
```

**controllers/cards_controller**

```
def index
  @cards= Card.all
end

def card_params
   params.require(:card).permit(
      :name,
      :phone,
      :email
end
```

i am starting with ajax and would like to know what would be the best solution to make get requests using jquery and native rails resources.

i would like for example to click on link

`<a href="#" class="link-show-email">Show Email</a>`

render the field `card.email` and append it to the

`<div id="show-email-<%= card.id %>"></div>`

this is a sample html, so it can be changed, if need correction or more information i can provide! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note if you use a partial to render each of your cards record, then you'll have multiple classes with the same id, so, the idea to add the id of the object will be useless, you could try editing your cards partial to something like:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <p><%= card.name %></p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="link-show-phone-<%= card.id %>">
      Show Phone
    </a>
  </p>
  <p><div id="show-phone-<%= card.id %>"></div></p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="link-show-email-<%= card.id %>">
      Show Email
    </a>
  <p>
  <p><div id="show-email-<%= card.id %>"></div><p>
</div>
```

This way whenever you click on show phone or email, you'll get the attribute you want to get, and the id of the record.

So with that you can create an script with listeners for your `a` elements, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("[class^='link-show']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let attrs = $(this).attr('class').split('-')
    let attr  = attrs[2]
    let el    = attrs.pop()
    $.get({ url: '/cards/' + el + '/' + attr })
  });
</script>
```

There you add a click event listener to each element that starts with the class `link-show`, then get the attribute and id, prevent the default behavior, and make the GET request.

As the url points to `cards/:id/:attribute` then you need to create the method and route:

```
def show_attribute
  @card = Card.find(params[:id])
  @attribute = @card[params[:attribute]]
end
```

Here the method recevies the `id` and `attribute` as params, use `find` to get the card with the passed id, and then set the attribute needed to a variable called `@attribute`.

The route specifies what params to expect and tells the controller and method:

```
get '/cards/:id/:attribute', to: 'cards#show_attribute'
```

As finally you just need the `js.erb` file which will update the content in the DOM:

```
$('#show-<%= "#{params[:attribute]}-#{params[:id]}" %>').html('<%= escape_javascript(@attribute) %>')
```

It gets the `#show-` element, depending on what attribute you need, and use the `params[:id]` to identify it, then sets the attribute needed that was created in the controller.

Hope it helps.